# Is it possible to automatically detect types in Specflow tables?

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow, gherkin

If I have a Techtalk.Specflow.Table, is it possible to detect automatically the appropriate types of the elements in the table ?

For exemple, if I have the following steps :

```
Given the following ticket sold on the 2019-01-01
|TicketId|Owner     |Amount|Seat|
|0033    |John Doe  |20.00 |3F  |
```

If I define my step like this

```
[Given(@"Given the following ticket sold on the (.*)")]
public void GivenTheFollowingPosition(DateTime date, Table table)
{
}
```

Specflow is capable of detecting and cast the date correctly. Therefore I assume it should also be capable of doing so for the elements of the table. Do you know if it is possible to achieve it and how ?

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SpecFlow Assist Helpers](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers). There are a few helpful methods, you can try to use `table.CreateInstance<T>` method to convert row in your table to object for future use. You can also specify the custom mapping using `TableAliases` attribute, see [Working Effectively with SpecFlow Tables](https://joebuschmann.com/posts/2018/08/working-effectively-with-specflow-tables/) article for details